Azure Server responded with status 429. Error message: {'error': {'code': '429', 'message': 'Rate limit is exceeded. Try again in 57 seconds.'}}

The token I used to ask this question is only 16 tokens. I searched the internet for the error  I received

Server responded with status 429. Error message: {'error': {'code': '429', 'message': 'Rate limit is exceeded. Try again in 57 seconds.'}}

and it suggested that I should scale my services. I scaled my search service to the maximum 36/36, but I still encountered the same error.
How to resolve this issue?


I resolved the issue by adjusting the Tokens per Minute rate limit to a higher value. Initially, it was set to the default of about 10,000.


I am currently training to learn Azure AI Studio and have been encountering a frustrating error: "Server responded with status 429. Error message: {'error': {'code': '429', 'message': 'Rate limit is exceeded. Try again in 59 seconds.'}}" This error occurs specifically when I add a datastore and then attempt to index it. My data has been uploaded and indexed successfully. I have deployed the GPT-4.0 mini model with a rate limit of 8,000 tokens per minute. Additionally, the text-embedding-ada-002 model has been automatically deployed, and I increased its rate limit to 240,000 tokens per minute.
